# New activity start every time on receiving sms using broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I am having an issue while using my own sms app that starts a new activity everytime a new sms comes.I want to populate the new sms in the alredy opened activity.
I am using

```
Intent data = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
// new activity
data.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Please let me know where I am doing wrong?
Ali

Answer (score 0):

Try use this flag:

```
Intent data = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
new activity
data.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

please refer to this [Intent Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code. 
If your activity is already created but not yet finished or destroyed then this call will get your activity to screen without creating it again.

```
public void showActivity()
{
 Intent data = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    data.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make launch mode of your activity single Instance in your AndroidManifest..

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
```